# Testing user input against a list in python

Tags: python

I need to test if the user input is the same as an element of a list, right now I'm doing this:

```
cars = ("red", "yellow", "blue")
guess = str(input())

if guess == cars[1] or guess == cars[2]:
        print("success!")
```

But I'm working with bigger lists and my if statement is growing a lot with all those checks, is there a way to reference multiple indexes something like:

```
if guess == cars[1] or cars[2]
```

or

```
if guess == cars[1,2,3]
```

Reading the lists docs I saw that it's impossible to reference more than one index like, I tried above and of course that sends a syntax error.

Comment: Is it intentional that you're not looking at `cars[0]`?  Lists are indexed from zero, so your three cars are `cars[0]`, `cars[1]` and `cars[2]`.

Comment: i really hope you're using python 3.x...otherwise use raw_input instead of input and print 'succes!', without brackets

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of the 0 index in list thanks, And yes it is python 3.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
if guess in cars:
    ...
```

but if your list was huge, that would be slow.  You should then store your list of cars in a set:

```
cars_set = set(cars)
....
if guess in cars_set:
    ...
```

Checking whether something is present is a set is much quicker than checking whether it's in a list (but this only becomes an issue when you have many many items, and you're doing the check several times.)

(Edit: I'm assuming that the omission of `cars[0]` from the code in the question is an accident.  If it isn't, then use `cars[1:]` instead of `cars`.)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. In the first example his code would not print success if `guess` is `"red"`, but your code would.

Comment: Something to note here is that set construction, while efficient, may be a point of overhead if you're only checking the list once.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe I misunderstood and he simply made a mistake in his example code...

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah it was a mistake, but i'll keep that in mind, in, was what i needed :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `guess in cars` to test if `guess` is equal to an element in `cars`:

```
cars = ("red","yellow","blue")
guess = str(input())

if guess in cars:
        print ("success!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `in`:

```
if guess in cars:
    print( 'success!' )
```

See also the possible operations on sequence type as documented [in the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange).

Answer (score 0):

@Sean Hobbs:
First you'd have to assign a value to the variable index.

```
index = 0
```

You might want to use while True to create the infinite loop, so your code would be like this:

```
while True:

    champ = input("Guess a champion: ")
    champ = str(champ)

    found_champ = False
    for i in listC:
        if champ == i:
            found_champ = True

    if found_champ:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```