# How do I take a users input and see if it's in the list

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a way to take 2 user's inputs and see if it is in the list I have created before. Then if it is, then I print out the name of the users input but then if it isn't I have to say there is none.
Here's an example:

Say they are all named and I wanted to print out the name of the person. Not duplicate.

```
[['Jon', 12, 167],['Sam', 18, 200]]
```

Comment: here if word in list1: print(name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing user input against a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944655/testing-user-input-against-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Nah, what happens if I wanted to say print the person with the car

Comment: ['Sam', red],['Jon', blue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_data = [['Jon', 12, 167],['Sam', 18, 200]]
user_input1 = int(input())
user_input2 = int(input())
my_output = ""
for i in my_data:
    print(i[1],i[2],user_input1,user_input2)
    if (i[1] == user_input1 and i[2] == user_input2):
        my_output = i[0]
        break
    else:
        my_output = "No Data Found!"
print(my_output)
```

if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: but it says after that 'no data found'

Comment: And also, say I wanted the user to input to be a number and say that there are 2 user inputs and say it was 12 and 167, how do I say it is Jon?

Comment: I have edited the code to accept two input and check them against the data and return the finding. I hope it helps.